# How can I put two delegate to one viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want AddContentViewController to have two delegate, but keeping getting error, how can I do that?

```
@interface AddContentViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
 <CatPickViewControllerDelegate>
```

thx 4 help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this:

```
@interface AddContentViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, CatPickViewControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 3):

seprated by comma

```
@interface AddContentViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,CatPickViewControllerDelegate>
```